# Сохранение изменений в json-файл. В чем ошибка?

Tags: ajax, json, post

```
$("#save").on("click",function(){
var needed_nickname = 'coldunox';
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'json_data.json', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {          
        for (var i in data) {
            for (var j in data[i].members) {
                if (data[i].members[j].nick.text == needed_nickname) {
                    data[i].members[j].firstname.text=$('#firstname').value;
                    data[i].members[j].lastname.text$('#lastname').value;
                    data[i].members[j].number.text=$('#phone').value;
                    data[i].members[j].email.text=$('#email').value;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: напишите вашу ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напрямую в файл json записать не получится *(представьте, что было бы, если бы все клиентские скрипты имели доступ на запись к объектам файловой подсистемы веб-сервера).*

Вы должны делать POST-запрос на url, который обрабатывается вашим веб-сервером, и уже в серверной логике десериализовать данные, записывать их в файл и тп.